# Advice on displaying last record in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i want to display the last record in the database

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from"+TABLE_NAME,null);
```

This code displays all records. What must I do to only display the last entry?

Comment: You can use DESC and make a LIMIT 1

Comment: Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+ "order by desc limit 1",null); This just crashes.

Comment: You need to add space between `+TABLE_NAME+ "order` e.g. `+TABLE_NAME+ " order`. And you did not specify **The order base on**.

Comment: Ahh thank you. lol. Forgot to order by id

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use limit keyword in sql like this :**

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY table_idx DESC LIMIT 1", null);
```